# How to stop Mac reconnecting network volume

Tags: macos, mount, nas

I have a network volume on my NAS (QNAP) that my Mac keeps remounting (unless I turn off the NAS - which defeats the object).

I did have it at one time in my "Login Items", but it has since been deleted.

If I turn the NAS back on, eventually the mount point (it was mounted via afp, if that matters) re-appears. I also end up with multiple mounted occurrences in /Volumes folder, like it keeps getting remounted:

/Volumes/Multmedia
/Volumes/Multmedia-1
/Volumes/Multmedia-2
/Volumes/Multmedia-3
...
etc

I have searched around, but can't find anything obvious that is causing this.

Also, even after I "eject" the remote volume it gets remounted sometime later, but what surprised me is that I see no errors shown if I turn off the NAS. I've checked the console log, but there's so much there I could easily has missed it.

--

Edit: after following @GordonDavisson suggest and running the `fs_usage` for hours, it finally re-appeared:

```
17:59:54  mkdir             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000029   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54    HFS_update      /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000001   diskarbitrat
17:59:54  mkdir             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000093   diskarbitrat
17:59:54    HFS_update      /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000001   diskarbitrat
17:59:54  chown             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000014   diskarbitrat
17:59:54  open              /Volumes/Multimedia/.autodiskmounted         0.000053   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000006   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  lstat64           /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000010   fseventsd   
17:59:54  fsgetpath         /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   Finder      
17:59:54  fsgetpath         /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   Google Chrom
17:59:54  fsgetpath         /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000002   com.apple.ap
17:59:54  mount             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.004279   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000005   coreservices
17:59:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000008   diskarbitrat
17:59:54  pathconf          /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   coreservices
17:59:54  pathconf          /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000001   coreservices
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000025   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000004   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000012   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000002   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000002   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000003   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000012   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  fsctl             /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000002   NetAuthSysAg
17:59:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000009   mds         
17:59:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/Multimedia                          0.000006   mds
```

So, it looks like `NetAuthSysAg` has something to do with it.

Comment: My guess would be that some program has alias to the server volume, or some file or folder on it, and is reconnecting to get at that file/folder. Can you correlate when it remounts with something you're running or doing?

Comment: No correlation so far. I've tried. The time period between me unmounting/ejecting the volume and it reappearing is long enough for me to not time it (especially when I am trying to get other things done, on other desktops/spaces). Your guess matches mine - but finding that process is what eludes me.

Comment: One other idea: eject the volume, then run `sudo fs_usage | grep '/Volumes/Multimedia'`, enter your admin password, then leave it running and see what shows up when the volume gets remounted.

Comment: Turned on the NAS before I saw the previous comment. After a while, it magically reconnected the single volume. At least twice, because it created both /Volumes/Multimedia and /Volumes/Multimedia-1. Only one of them showed up as a mounted volume on the desktop. So, I ejected it (and rm'd the other). Running the suggested `sudo fs_usage | grep '/Volumes/Multimedia'` from @GordonDavisson (thank you). It's been 4+ hours and although I see multiple references to `/Volumes/Multimedia`, it hasn't reappeared as a mounted volume. Most frequent "culprits" are `getattrlist` and an occasional `lstat64`.

Comment: getattrlist and lstat64 are the operations being done; look in the last column for the program accessing them. Note that even if it hasn't remounted, just seeing it in the `fs_usage` output is enough to tell you that those programs remember it for one reason or another, and therefore belong on the list of suspects for causing the actual problem.

Comment: NetSysAuthAgent handles authenticating to file servers, so that's not suspicious. Similarly, diskarbitrationd, fseventsd, mds, and Finder are all things I expect to show up whenever something is mounted. Not sure about coreservices and com.apple.apsomething. Google Chrome, though, looks really suspicious to me, so I'd try quitting it for a while and see if the automounts still happen (& if so, if there's something different in the fs_usage output). Anything else after this, with a process touching something *in* the volume, not just the volume folder itself?

Comment: The plot thickens... or the mystery deepens... Since updating to OSX 10.12.2 a few days ago, the volume hasn't reappeared...